# Table A references table B, how do I insert (using Perl and DBI and PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, foreign-keys, dbi

Consider the case where you have table A referencing table B:

```
create table tableA
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   information VARCHAR(32)
);
create table tableB
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   tableAid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tableA(id),
   other_information VARCHAR(32)
):
```

Note that I am writing my code in Perl, and the database is PostgreSQL.

So, I have 2 `tableB` entries that are tied to a single `tableA` entry. I want to say something like:

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=mydb;host=localhost","userid","password",('RaiseError' -> 1));

my $otherinfo = "other info, Table B";
my $moreotherinfo = "more other info, table B";
my info = "table A info";
my $insertitA = $dbh->prepare("insert into tableA (information) values (?)");
my $insertitB = $dbh->prepare("insert into tableB (tableAid,other_information) values (?,?)");
my $nrowsA = $insertitA($info);
my $tableAidreference = ????;
my $nrowsB = $insertitB($tableAidreference, $otherinfo);
my $nrowsB2 = $insertitB($tableAidreference, $moreotherinfo);
```

Where do I get `$tableAidreference`? Do I have to search `tableA` for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method with calling `nextval('seq_name')` separately for the purpose of a subsequent `INSERT` is outdated and very inefficient. It requires an additional round-trip to the server. Don't use this. There are better options:

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b4632/1)

First, I modified your test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a
(  tbl_a_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   information text
);
CREATE TABLE tbl_b
(  tbl_b_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   tbl_a_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_a(tbl_a_id),
   other_information text
);
```

- Don't use `id` as column name, it's not descriptive. Some not-so-smart ORMs do that, it's an anti-pattern.
- Don't use mixed case identifiers in PostgreSQL if you can avoid it.
- Use the [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) type for surrogate primary keys.

Then, do it all in one [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later) making use of the `RETURNING` clause of the [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) command:

```
WITH x AS (
    INSERT INTO tbl_a (information)
    VALUES ('foo')
    RETURNING tbl_a_id
    )
INSERT INTO tbl_b (tbl_a_id, other_information)
SELECT tbl_a_id, 'bar'
FROM   x
RETURNING tbl_a_id, tbl_b_id; -- optional, if you want IDs back
```

**One** round trip to the server and you get both new IDs back if you want - instead of **three** round trips.

---

#### How to use this with DBI?

With the DBD::Pg module:

```
$SQL = q{ WITH x AS (
    INSERT INTO tbl_a (information)
    VALUES (?) 
    RETURNING tbl_a_id
    )
INSERT INTO tbl_b (tbl_a_id, other_information)
SELECT tbl_a_id, 'bar'
FROM   x
RETURNING tbl_a_id, tbl_b_id};
$answer = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
$sth->execute('foo');
$tbl_a_id = $answer->fetch()->[0];
$tbl_b_id = $answer->fetch()->[1];
```

Untested. There is a complete [example how to do it in the `DBD::Pg` manual](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eturnstep/DBD-Pg-2.19.3/Pg.pm#execute).

Comment: So, if I say `$doit = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO tbl_a (information) VALUES (?) RETURNING tbl_a_id"); $ans = $doit->execute('other'); print "$ans";` I get '1', for number of rows affected.  How do I get back the tbl_a_id?

Comment: @rustycar: I added an example and a link to my answer.

Comment: Why do you think `nextval` is outdated? It's still the only way to get a sequence value without doing an actual insert.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am not saying `nextval()` itself is outdated. I am saying the workflow of querying the `id` for an `INSERT` separately is outdated. This was the way to do it before the `RETURNING` clause was introduced with Postgres 8.2. One round trip to the server beats two (or three in this case). I clarified my wording a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you handle the primary key. Generally your best bet would be to handle the increment yourself by selecting the value from a sequence. If we assume `tableA.id` is incremented with a sequence, then you could perform an additional select from the database by executing an SQL statement like:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name'); <-- where seq_name is the name of the sequence you create
```

You would select that value, then use the value you retrieved from the database to set the `id` parameter in the modified insert below:

```
my $insertitA = $dbh->prepare("insert into tableA (id, information) values (?, ?)");
```

Since you have explicitly selected the value, you will be able to insert that into the referencing table as well.

Comment: These methods are not quite up to date.